# referencing a Unit Test FrameWork attribute from a non-test project

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, assemblies, reference

I am using .NET 3.5 and VS2010 and I am trying to look for test methods and test classes in an assembly.  I would like to use the Type.GetCustomAttributes(Type, Boolean) method because this allows me to search directly for these attributes as opposed to getting all attributes and iterating through doing a string comparison.

To accomplish this I would need to reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, which doesn't seem to be possible outside of a test project.  I have already tried editing the xml and it didn't work.

Here is an example of the code I would like to use

```
var atts = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethod),false)
if (atts.Length > 0)
do something
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible to reference that assembly in a "normal" project?

Comment: It's not listed in the list of assemblies when I try to add it from visual studio

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` assembly to a normal project. The reason, why it doesn't appear in your "Add reference" dialog is, that your project targets either the ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" or the ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". Change the "Target framework" to either ".NET Framework 3.5" or ".NET Framework 4" in the "Application" tab of your project properties.